# Поиск по двум таблицам

Tags: sql

Найти количество клиентов, оставшихся без взаимодействия в категории просрочки (dpd) 30+:
Таблица - Contact

```
ID_client | ID_Dogovor | Date_contact | type
----------+------------+--------------+--------
        1 |     215635 |         null | null
        1 |    2315534 |         null | null
        3 |     134548 |   08.09.2018 | letter
        4 |     215496 |         null | null
        5 |      25354 |         null | null
        5 |   32135496 |   15.02.2018 | sms
```

Таблица - Dogovor

```
ID_client | ID_Dogovor | dpd
----------+------------+-----
        1 |     215635 |   0
        2 |    5458632 |  78
        3 |     134548 |  23
        1 |    2315534 | 138
        4 |     215496 | 366
        5 |      25354 |   5
        5 |   32135496 |  89
```

Возможно:

```sql
select *
from Contact
where Date_contact = NULL

UNION ALL

select *
from Dogovor
where dpd > 30+
```

Или нужно через JOIN?

Comment: Наталья, уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы хотите? Что такое категория просрочки (dpd) 30+?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вашего вопроса, то ответ будет таким:

```sql
select count(*)
from Contact c
join Dogovor d on
    d.ID_client = c.ID_client and
    d.ID_Dogovor = c.ID_Dogovor and
    d.dpd >= 30
where c.Date_contact is null
```

Здесь мы соединяем две таблицы по `ID_client` и `ID_Dogovor`, но только для тех записей из `Dogovor`, в которых `dpd >= 30`, после чего оставляем в итоговой выборке только те, записи из `Contact`, в которых `Date_contact is null`, и считаем их количество агрегатной функцией `count`.

Удачи!